# How do I add Bootstrap Burger Menu Functionality to a Regular Bootsrap Menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

This menu needs to become a Bootstrap burger menu on resolutions with widths 992px and below.

I am using Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row navbar">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1"><a class="btn" href="index.html">Home</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"><a class="btn" href="prices.html">Our Prices</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"><a class="btn" href="location.html">Location</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"><a class="btn" href="about.html">About Us</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"><a class="btn" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'entirely columns'. Do you want the menu to appear like this when the user clicks the hamburger or do you want to add a burger menu to the end of these columns??

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a class="btn" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn" href="prices.html">Our Prices</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn" href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn" href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```